# Change style of specific <option> in DDL

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Method to Create DDL**

```
var groups = lstActivity.OrderBy(x => x.codeAC.Text).ThenBy(x => lstTraining.IndexOf(x.text)).ThenBy(x => x.text).GroupBy(x => x.codeAC.Text).OrderBy(g => lstCategories.IndexOf(g.Key));

foreach(var group in groups)
{
    var slg = new SelectListGroup() { Name = group.Key };

    foreach(codeAC activity in group)
    {
        SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem() { Text = activity.text, Value = activity.ID.ToString(), Group = slg };
        lstAssignments.Add(item);
    }
}
```

**CSHTML:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("activityID", null, "-- Select Activity --", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "activityID", @class = "form-control" })
```

**How it renders in HTML:**

```
<select name="activityID" class="form-control valid" id="activityID">
    <option value="">-- Select Activity --</option>
    <optgroup label="Test Group 1">
        <option value="7">TEST 1</option>
        <option value="6">TEST 2</option>
        <option value="5">TEST 3</option>
        <option value="4">TEST 4</option>
        <option value="2">TEST 5</option>
        <option value="1">TEST 6</option>
        <option value="10">TEST 7</option>
        <option value="9">TEST 8</option>
        <option value="8">TEST 9</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Test Group 2">
        <option value="11">TEST 10</option>
        <option value="12">TEST 11</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

My Question is.. how can I get the `options` under the `optgroup Test Group 2` to be in red on page load?

Comment: Can you add a class to optgroup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CSS attribute selector: `optgroup[label="Test Group 2"]`

```css
optgroup[label="Test Group 2"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select name="activityID" class="form-control valid" id="activityID">
  <option value="">-- Select Activity --</option>
  <optgroup label="Test Group 1">
    <option value="7">TEST 1</option>
    <option value="6">TEST 2</option>
    <option value="5">TEST 3</option>
    <option value="4">TEST 4</option>
    <option value="2">TEST 5</option>
    <option value="1">TEST 6</option>
    <option value="10">TEST 7</option>
    <option value="9">TEST 8</option>
    <option value="8">TEST 9</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Test Group 2">
    <option value="11">TEST 10</option>
    <option value="12">TEST 11</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```